# Count unique occurrences of a field across multiple files

Tags: bash, awk

I have a large collection of log files where each file contains records of the form ...

```
2015-06-07 23:59:53 [uid:123] {success,1} .
```

For each file, I want to count how many unique UIDs are present.

So in this file snippet we see the uids 123 and 124 ...

```
2015-06-07 23:59:53 [uid:123] {success,1}
2015-06-07 23:59:53 [uid:123] {success,1}
2015-06-07 23:59:53 [uid:123] {success,1}
2015-06-07 23:59:53 [uid:124] {success,1}
```

so the result of my count for this file would be **2**.

How can I get the data using bash and/or awk?

I tried

```
cat 20150607.log | awk '{print $3}' | sort | uniq | wc -l
```

This worked well, but the problem is I have so many files and I do not want to run the above command one by one.

Is there a simpler way of getting this count accross multiple files?

Comment: `for i in *.log; do echo -n "$i: "; awk '{ print $3 }' "$i" | sort -u | wc -l; done` ?

Comment: @melpomene How can I run the command? Use bash? It will be best fo me to have a simple command , like awk and more.

Comment: it is not very clear what you mean. Mind to edit, show more representative data and its desired output?

Comment: @gangzi I have edited your question to make it clearer. In doing so I now have a question about your question ... do you want to constrain the unique uid count on a *per file* basis or do you want to get a unique uid count across *all the files*

Comment: @RobKielty I want to constrain the unique uid count on a per file basis.

Answer (score 8):

Using GNU awk for `ENDFILE` and `length(array)`:

```
awk '{unq[$3]} ENDFILE{print FILENAME, length(unq); delete unq}' *.log
```

With other awks:

```
awk '
    !seen[FILENAME,$3]++ { unq[FILENAME]++ }
    END { for (i=1;i<ARGC;i++) print ARGV[i], unq[ARGV[i]]+0 }
' *.log
```