# sed/awk copy paste snippet from one place to other place in same file

Tags: regex, linux, awk, sed

How do i copy some snippet and paste in same file using `sed/awk` tool?

Example: file name `foo.txt` has following text i want to copy that and paste below that same text

```
ABC
DEF
GHI
JKL
MNO
PQR
```

Final output will be like.

```
    ABC
    DEF
    GHI
    JKL
    MNO
    PQR

    ABC
    DEF
    GHI
    JKL
    MNO
    PQR
```

Comment: is this the only content of the file or it is part of a bigger file? How do you determine this part, based on a pattern or on line number?

Comment: @fedorqui its example... I just want to know how `sed/awk` can handle that... it is interesting i never thought about i will get stuck issue like that...

Comment: I'm assuming this is for learning purposes, right?  Otherwise `cat input_file input_file` works as well.

Comment: It's just silly. You'd never use sed or awk for this so asking how to do it in sed or awk is like asking how put a nail in a wall using a screwdriver. Yeah you can do it, but when you have a hammer in your toolbox...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OP asked for sed, so here it is!

There are probably many way to achieve it, but here is the one I know:

```
sed 'H;$G' foo.txt
```

- `H`: append current file to the [hold buffer](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Execution-Cycle.html)
- `;`: separate two expressions
- `$`: upon end of file
- `G`: print hold buffer

### But wait! there is more!

Don't ever forget that *`ed` Is The Standard Text Editor* (took me some time to remember how to use it and it was not brillant I must say).

For the example let's say it's in a file named `foo.ed` (you could do the same in an interactive session):

```
$a

.
,t$
$d
wq
```

Then use it with:

```
ed foo.txt < foo.ed
```

One-liner unreadable bashism:

```
ed foo.txt <<< $'$a\n\n.\n,t$\n$d\nwq'
```

Translation:

- `$a`: insert at the end of the file everything (a single new line here) till the single dot `.`
- `,t$`: copy the whole file content to the end
- `$d`: delete the last line because I didn't remember how to copy till the line before the end of the file !@#
- `wq`: write and quit

References:

- http://www.gnu.org/software/ed/manual/ed_manual.html
- http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?EdIsTheStandardTextEditor

Comment: Just to clarify: `H` appends  a newline and then the contents of the pattern space to the hold space. `G` appends a newline and then the contents of the hold space to the pattern space. The default behaviour of sed print process re-attaches a newline to the pattern space before printing. So the `$G` command prints the last line of the file, two newlines and then the contents of the hold space i.e. the entire file.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you want to duplicate a whole file and don't really want to indent the output lines, you'd never use sed or awk for this, just cat and echo:

```
$ cat file; echo ''; cat file
$ cat file
ABC
DEF
GHI
JKL
MNO
PQR

ABC
DEF
GHI
JKL
MNO
PQR
```

and if you want to modify the original file, just redirect the output to a tmp file and then mv it to file:

```
(cat file; echo ''; cat file) > tmp && mv tmp file
```

Answer (score 1):

As Fedorqui points out in his comment, you can run Awk on the same file multiple times.

```
awk 'NR>1 && FNR==1 {print ""} {print "\t" $0}' foo.txt foo.txt
```

should produce your desired output.

This can be simplified using [bash brace expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/brace) `foo.txt{,}`.

Also, if using GNU Awk, there's builtin rule called [`ENDFILE`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/BEGINFILE_002fENDFILE.html) that will allow you act after the last record has been processed in each file:

```
awk '{print "\t" $0} ENDFILE{print ""}' foo.txt{,}
```

Alternatively, you could be a hog and read the entire file into memory, then loop through it twice.

```
awk '{
    a[NR]=$0
} END {
    num=2
    for (i=1; i<=num; i++) {
        for (j=1; j<=NR; j++)
            print "\t"a[j]
        if (i % num != 0)
            print ""
    }
}' foo.txt
```

You'll notice each line number `NR` must also be recorded as an index of the array `a` to preserve the original order in output.

Comment: Storing all the file in memory may be a bit overkilling. What about just `awk '{print "\t" $0}' file file`?

Comment: @fedorqui The only reason it's necessary is because the entire file needs to be printed twice.  At that point, doing `awk '{print "\t" $0}' file; echo; awk '{print "\t" $0}' file` is repetitive.  I guess I should be more clear about the reasoning in the answer, but what about if he needed to print the file `n` times with a tab prefix?

Comment: But, still, there is no need to store things in memory. You have to tweak the way you provide the files, so that it gets many. For example, you can say `awk '1' file{,,,,}` to print it 5 times (every comma adds one + the initial one). Also, the question is a bit broad, so any kind of solution might be good here.

Comment: @fedorqui Wow, I did not know you could do that.  The question is kind of broad, but how would you print the empty line between each copy's output in a `awk '{print "\t" $0}' file{,,}` scenario?

Comment: Since you are working with different files, you can play with NR and FNR. `NR` stands for all the content, whereas FNR affects to current file you are processing. So you can for example write `awk 'NR>1 && FNR==1 {print ""} {print "\t" $0}' file{,,}`

Comment: @fedorqui Cool, that makes total sense.  I'm familiar with using FNR and NR in multiple files, but never thought to use it or knew it could be used on the same file multiple times.  Thanks for the lesson!  I'm going to delete my answer now as it's probably not useful for anyone.  What you put in the last comment is a much better answer.

Comment: Also interesting the [`ENFILE`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31750224/1983854) thingy

Comment: No problem, do not delete your answer! It is always useful to see the discussion for future reference. If you want, feel free to use my comment as an alternative answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85182/discussion-between-john-b-and-fedorqui).